# Roots of $x^4+2x^3+2=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, roots

The complex numbers $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3$, and $\alpha_4$ are the four distinct roots of the equation $x^4+2x^3+2=0$. Determine the unordered set$$
\{\alpha_1\alpha_2 + \alpha_3\alpha_4, \alpha_1\alpha_3 + \alpha_2\alpha_4, \alpha_1\alpha_4 + \alpha_2\alpha_3\}.
$$

---

I think I should use Vieta's Formulas for this one, so I have $$\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3+\alpha_4=-2,$$ $$\alpha_1\alpha_2+\alpha_1\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_3\alpha_4=0,$$
$$\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3+\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_4+\alpha_1\alpha_3\alpha_4+\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=0,$$
$$\alpha_1\alpha_2\alpha_3\alpha_4=2$$

However, I'm not quite sure how to proceed from here. I know the three elements in the set sum to $0$, but this doesn't seem to help at the moment.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Assume that the three numbers $x,y,z$ that you want are roots of a cubic equation. Find its coefficients: $x+y+z, xy+yz+xz, xyz$ and solve the cubic equation.

Comment: I got $x+y+z$, but I can't seem to find the values of $xy+yz+xz$ and $xyz$.

Comment: Isn't $xyz$ a symmetric polynomial in $\alpha_1,..., \alpha_4$?

Comment: It is, but I'm not sure how to use Vieta's to find it.

Comment: Every symmetric polynomial is a polynomial of elementary symmetric polynomials.

Comment: Hi! I saw your recent post calling out a cheating attempt on the "EUCLID 2022 TEST". I fully support your anti-cheating stance, so please continue revealing cheaters! Please also post it in [CURED](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/cured) to alert the regular participants there (which two of the moderators also frequent) so that we can more quickly close+delete such cheating attempts and recognize future posts from such cheaters. Thanks! (Also feel free to post any other close/delete requests there.)